# Find a Value and insert a row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find

```
Sub o()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For y = 2 To 2
For x = 1 To 600
    If Cells(x, y).Value = "CD Sector Average" Then
        Cells(x, y).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(x + 2, y).Select
    End If
Next x
Next y

For y = 2 To 2
For x = 1 To 600
    Next x
    If Cells(x, y).Value = "CS Sector Average" Then
        Cells(x, y).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(x + 2, y).Select
    End If
Next x
Next y


For y = 2 To 2
For x = 1 To 600
    Next x
    If Cells(x, y).Value = "E Sector Average" Then
        Cells(x, y).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(x + 2, y).Select
    End If
Next x
Next y
End Sub
```

So what i am looking for is for it to find the first value and add the row above and then continue searching for the next value and add a row.

What it does is it inserts rows before the first value until it hits the 600 range then the macro ends.

How can this be altered to just run the find and insert one time and then move to the next value to find?

Comment: The values are in the order that they will be found in the sheet, but the input data will change what row they are found on depending on how many entries there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're working in the wrong direction.  With your loop, if it finds the value in row 5 (x = 5), for example, it will add a row and shift the row where the value was found down (in this case from 5 to 6).  When your FOR loop iterates, it moves to the next row (x = 6) and finds that same exact row that we just moved.
To fix this, you need to work backwards.  This is always a good practice when performing a function like this, or when deleting specific rows.  To work backwards, you just need to make a small change to your FOR loop.  Try changing it to:
`For x = 600 to 1 Step -1`
This tells Excel to go from 600 to 1, iterating by -1 at a time, avoiding the problem you're seeing.